# Caught In Potential Infinite Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am simply trying to make a list of district names and District objects from a pandas DataFrame, but for some reason, the code never finishes running. I can't see anywhere that could become an infinite loop, so it is beyond me as to why it gets stuck every time I run it. Here is the section that is getting stuck (particularly the j-iterated for loop):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#make dataframe
data = pd.read_csv('gun-violence-data_01-2013_03-2018.csv', header=0, delimiter=',')

#drop data points with null condressional district values
data = data[data.congressional_district != 0]
data.dropna(axis=0,how='any',subset=['congressional_district'],inplace= True)

#constructing working table
table = data[['incident_id','state','congressional_district']]

#list of districts. Formatting in original file must be corrected to analyze data
districtNames = ['filler1','filler2']
districts = []
s = table.shape

#loop thru the rows of the table
for i in range(s[0]):
    check = True

    #build strings for each district
    ds = table.iloc[i,1] + str(table.iloc[i,2])
    #testString = str(table.iloc[i,2])

    #append ds to districtNames if it isnt in already
    #make array of District Objects
    for j in range(len(districtNames)):
        if(ds == districtNames[j]):
            check = False
        if(check):
            districtNames.append(ds)
            districts.append(District(ds,0))
```

For reference, here is the District class:

```
class District:
def __init__(self, name, count):
    self._name = name
    self._count = count
def get_name(self):
    return name
def get_count(self):
    return count
def updateCount(self,amount):
    self._count += amount
```

The initial .csv file is quite large, and after cutting out some of the data points in the 8th and 9th lines, I have 227,312 data points left. I understand this is quite a few, but the code doesn't even finish after running for 5 minutes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put in some print lines and debug

Comment: not a fix but you could shorten `for j in range(len(districtNames)):` to `for districtName in districtNames:`

Comment: print is your friend here, stick one at the start of each loop just so you can see whats ocuring and that stuff is progressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it won't terminate, but that it is inefficient in its current state.  Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class District:
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self._name = name
        self._count = count
    def get_name(self):
        return name
    def get_count(self):
        return count
    def updateCount(self,amount):
        self._count += amount

#make dataframe
data = pd.read_csv('gun-violence-data_01-2013_03-2018.csv', header=0, delimiter=',')

#drop data points with null condressional district values
data = data[data.congressional_district != 0]
data.dropna(axis=0,how='any',subset=['congressional_district'],inplace= True)

#constructing working table
table = data[['incident_id','state','congressional_district']]

#list of districts. Formatting in original file must be corrected to analyze data
districtNames = (table.state + table.congressional_district.astype(str)).unique()
districts = list(map(lambda districtName: District(districtName, 0), districtNames))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had no idea you could even do that in Python. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tqdm` package to see in which loop your code sticks.

```
import tqdm from tqdm 
for i in tqdm(range(s[0]), position=0, leave=True):
    check = True

    #build strings for each district
    ds = table.iloc[i,1] + str(table.iloc[i,2])
    #testString = str(table.iloc[i,2])

    #append ds to districtNames if it isnt in already
    #make array of District Objects
    for j in range(len(districtNames)):
        if(ds == districtNames[j]):
            check = False
        if(check):
            districtNames.append(ds)
            districts.append(District(ds,0))
```